# Elixir: generate a list of `n` occurrences of a given argument (similar to Haskell's replicate)

Tags: list, haskell, elixir

I want a [Elixir](http://elixir-lang.org/) function to generate a list of `n` occurrences of an argument, similar to [Haskell's `replicate`](http://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputprelude/replicate_f.html) function:

```
Input: replicate 3 5

Output: [5,5,5]

Input: replicate 5 "aa"

Output: ["aa","aa","aa","aa","aa"]

Input: replicate 5 'a'

Output: "aaaaa"
```

I have made a function to "replicate" an Integer `n`times:

```
import String

def replicate(number, n)
  String.duplicate(to_string(number), n) 
  |> split("", trim: true) 
  |> Enum.map(fn n -> String.to_integer(n) end
end
```

But that's doesn't match the specification :( . Could you help me?

Comment: [1] "But that's doesn't match the specification" -- In which way? (I suggest that you edit your question to mention that.) [2] While I'm not familiar with Elixir, it feels quite awkward to make a string out of the `number` argument only so that you can use `String.duplicate`. You probably should look for a more direct way of implementing the function.

Comment: There's also `List.duplicate/2`: `List.duplicate(5, 3) #=> [5, 5, 5]`.

Comment: @Dogbert on `iex` `List.duplicate(7, 3)` is returns `'\a\a\a'`, `List.duplicate(8, 3)` returns '\b\b\b' and so on... is this it's expected behavior?

Comment: @duplode absolutely, a more direct way of implementing the function is exactly what I want :)

Comment: @MarcusViníciusMonteiro yes, `[7, 7, 7] == '\a\a\a'`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30037914/elixir-lists-interpreted-as-char-lists.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```rb
def replicate(n, x), do: for _ <- 1..n, do: x
```

If you want the last case to return string then you should add definition for this type using guard, something like this:

```rb
def replicate(n, [x]) when is_integer(x), do: to_string(for _ <- 1..n, do: x)
def replicate(n, x), do: for _ <- 1..n, do: x

iex(1)> replicate 3, 5
[5, 5, 5]
iex(2)> replicate 3, 'a'
"aaa"
```

You can also use [String.duplicate/2](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/String.html#duplicate/2) and [List.duplicate/2](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/List.html#duplicate/2) as other suggested:

```rb
def replicate(n, x = [c]) when is_integer(c), do: String.duplicate(to_string(x), n)
def replicate(n, x), do: List.duplicate(x, n)
```

Also please note that Char list `'a'` and String `"a"` are [different things](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/binaries-strings-and-char-lists.html) in Elixir, so ensure you understand this correctly.

And finally if this is not a home task then I'd suggest not to reinvent bicycle but directly use functions from String and List module, when possible.

Comment: Your first function fails on a simple case like `replicate(0, :foo)`.

Answer (score 1):

Building on previous answer, but avoiding the replicate(0, :foo) bug.

def replicate(n, x), do: for i <- 0..n, i > 0, do: x