# How to Convert Codepoint to Integer in Elixir

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I'm new in phoenix/elixir and need help.

I try to place result of a ecto.query in variable like this

```
owner =
(from ex in "executors",
where: ex.email == ^account_name,
where: ex.pass_hash == ^pwd,
select: ex.id )
|> Repo.all()
```

And I need 'owner' to be an integer like ex.id, but it is like a char - '\a', 'M', etc.

How correctly get result from query with integer type or how transform it from codepoint to integer?

thanks in advance

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking for, please edit your question is. Please edit your question to make it clear what your question is?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Elixir lists interpreted as char lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30037914/elixir-lists-interpreted-as-char-lists)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'm using that variable no with inspect, I try to make another query and using 'owner' as condition, which need to be integer

Comment: And what happens if you use `owner` in another query? Did you mean to use `Repo.one` instead of `Repo.all`?

Comment: Yes, @Dogbert, `Repo.one` I should use. Such as mudasobwa says it return single result instead a list. List of integers is converted to list of `codepoint` and if I use `codepoint` such as parametr where I need `integer` it makes error - wrong parametr

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR**

```
[owner | _] =
    (from ex in "executors",
     where: ex.email == ^account_name,
     where: ex.pass_hash == ^pwd,
     select: ex.id )
    |> Repo.all()
```

**Explanation:**

`Repo.all()` returns a **list** of integers, not a single integer. Which is interpreted as a charlist when you examine it. If you are positive there is a single result, perform a match as above, or even:

```
[owner] = ...
```

Or, even better:

```
owner = (<QUERY>)
        |> Repo.one()
```

Comment: Thank you for your aswers. @mudasobwa answer was most helpfull. `[owner] =...`  and `Repo.one()` work for me.