# How chunk_every method works in elixir?

Tags: elixir

`Enum.chunk_every([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 2)`

Gives output `[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]` on console.

But,  `Enum.chunk_every([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 2)`

Gives `[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], '\a\b']`

Why does it return ascii characters for some integers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a not a matter of `Enum.chunk_every/2`, but rather the fact that characters that are "printable" in terms of ASCII table, are displayed as ASCII characters.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30039460/3741729) answer.

To avoid that some people add `0` at the very end of very beginning of the list or you just ignore it - it case you need to check these integers you can:

```
a = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]]
IO.inspect a, charlists: :as_lists
```