# Elixir: ^A in list output

Tags: elixir

I have tried various ways to generate a list like:

```
 n = 3
 nodelist_master = Enum.into 1..n, []
```

But when I try and output them with IO.puts "List: #{nodelist_master}" or inspect I get

```
 ^A^B^C
```

I was expecting

```
 [1,2,3]
```

Comment: Can you post the `inspect` code that doesn't work?

Comment: My guess is he is tying`IO.puts nodelist_master` (which does give the output he reports) rather than simply `nodelist_master`  which gives `[1,2,3]`.  when you convert the list to string it gets interpreted as code-point command chars.

Comment: IO.inspect "List: #{nodelist_master}" which gives the same result as listed whereas IO.inspect nodelist_master works. Why should there be a difference?

Comment: @EdwardHasted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30037914/elixir-lists-interpreted-as-char-lists Basically simple answer is that when return codes from Erlang are passed back they're charlists.  Elixir usually wants to treat them as binaries--saves a lot of time when parsing error messages.  Those who built Elixir originally often had the need to see the charlists as their corresponding binaries and they knew how to get the other form back if they needed it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Elixir lists interpreted as char lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30037914/elixir-lists-interpreted-as-char-lists)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

String interpolation you used (`"#{list}"`) implicitly calls [`Kernel.to_string/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#to_string/1) on the argument.

```rb
iex|1 ▶ list = Enum.into 1..3, []
#⇒ [1, 2, 3]
iex|2 ▶ to_string(list)        
#⇒ <<1, 2, 3>>
```

Lists of integers are output as ASCII chars for values < 127:

```rb
iex|3 ▶ IO.puts to_string(list)
#⇒ ^A^B^C
:ok
```

The above are ASCII codes for `1`, `2`, and `3` respectively. For `65` (which is ASCII code for `"A"` char):

```rb
iex|3 ▶ IO.puts [65]
#⇒ A
```

---

[`IO.inspect`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/IO.html#inspect/1) implicitly calls [`Kernel.inspect/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#inspect/2) on the argument:

```rb
iex|4 ▶ inspect(list)
#⇒ "[1, 2, 3]"
iex|5 ▶ IO.inspect list, label: "List"
#⇒ List: [1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
```