# Why Am I Getting An Unbound Variable Message On This Ecto Query?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

Hey I am trying to make a query, my code look like this:

```
  def show(conn, _params) do
user = Guardian.Plug.current_resource(conn)
team = Web.get_team!(user.team.id)

score_query =
  from(
    u in User,
    where: u.team.id == team.id,
    select: sum(u.score)
  )

team_score = Repo.all(score_query)

IO.puts("score")
IO.inspect(team_score)

conn |> render("team.json", team: team)
```

And when I try to run it, I am getting an error that says:

```
** (Ecto.Query.CompileError) unbound variable `team` in query
```

but why is that unbound?
How can I fix it and why is it happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should [pin (`^`)](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#%5E/1) `team.id`:

```rb
score_query =
  from(
    u in User,
    #                   ⇓ HERE
    where: u.team.id == ^team.id,
    select: sum(u.score)
  )
```

---

As per [`Ecto.Query` documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#module-interpolation-and-casting):

> External values and Elixir expressions can be injected into a query expression with `^`:
>
> ```rb
> def with_minimum(age, height_ft) do
>   from u in "users",
>     where: u.age > ^age and u.height > ^(height_ft * 3.28),
>     select: u.name
> end
> ```

Comment: Hey, how can that be that if i have more than one lines that it should add up the result just says /v and no error?

Comment: I am not sure I follow. Could you please provide an example?

Comment: ok it seems random, I have a score of 5, i added 6 to it it gae the /v as a result, then i changed it to 12 and it worked the result as 17, and then i chnaged it back and the result was /n

Comment: I still do not follow. You probably have some context that I lack.

Comment: i see the scores in the database nicely as they are integers, and i get the sum of them as you see above, but as a result when I call IO.inspect the results are like '/a', '/n', '/v' for some reason

Comment: Ah. That’s the common famous surprise for newcomers :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30037914/elixir-lists-interpreted-as-char-lists (if you were to put proper backslash instead of forward slash I could get the issue sooner.)

Comment: oh so it means that the value is correct, just IO.inspect tries to help too much?

Comment: Yes, the value is correct. `IO.inspect` does not try anything, they are literally equal: `'\n' == [10] #⇒ true`.