# Why does my iex return a '-C' or a '-A' when I run this function

Tags: erlang, elixir, erlang-otp, elixir-iex

I've been learning Elixir for awhile now but I came across something today that totally confused me.

I made this filtering function:

```
thingy = for a <- ["may", "lay", "45", "67", "bay", "34"], do: Integer.parse(a)
for {n, _} <- thingy, do: n

output: '-C"'
```

Completely unexpected output, yet the version below 'works'

```
parseds = for i <- [ "10", "hot dogs", "20" ], do: Integer.parse(i)
for {n, _} <- parseds, do: n

output: [10, 20]
```

However if I change the numbers to something like 45 and 65 I get `'-A'` as the result.

Is this just the underlying binary functions permitting me from using which numbers I like?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30037914/elixir-lists-interpreted-as-char-lists and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52153483/why-is-elixirs-enum-count-not-returning-a-number/52153551#52153551

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Elixir lists interpreted as char lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30037914/elixir-lists-interpreted-as-char-lists)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because [Elixir, like Erlang, doesn't internally have a String type](https://www.culttt.com/2016/03/21/working-strings-elixir/). Single-quoted strings are represented as character lists, and these are commonly used when dealing with Erlang libraries. When you give Elixir the list `[45, 67, 34]`, it displays it as a list of [ASCII characters 46, 67, and 34](http://ee.hawaii.edu/~tep/EE160/Book/chap4/subsection2.1.1.1.html); which are `-`, `C`, and `"`.

If at least one number in your list doesn't represent a printable character, you see the list of numbers. Because `10` doesn't map to a printable character, in the second example, you see `10` and `20`.

It's important to note that the list you've created is still internally represented as `[45, 67, 34]` so any list operations you do will work exactly as you'd expect with your numbers.

Answer (score 2):

> This is because Elixir, like Erlang, doesn't internally have a String type

Whatever that means.  Strings, Smings.  It's as simple as:

```
iex(4)> [45, 67, 34]
'-C"'
```

In iex, a list of numbers is interpreted as a sequence of characters, where each number is a numerical code for some character.  If you look at an [ascii chart](http://www.asciitable.com), you will see that:

```
45 -> -
67 -> C
34 -> "
```

Look at this:

```
iex(5)> 'hi' == [104, 105]
true
```

In Elixir, `[104, 105]`and `[45, 67, 34]` are called charlists. A shortcut for creating the charlist `[104, 105]` is `'hi'`.  This is the result of a *terrible* feature of Erlang, but because Elixir is able to interface with Erlang, there is a need for charlists.  An Elixir charlist is the equivalent of an Erlang string, and an Erlang string is equivalent to a list of numbers.

Suppose your Elixir program does a bunch of critical mathematical calculations with the result being:

```
result = [76, 64, 78, 79]
```

and you want to display that info to the user so that they can tune a defibrillator's settings in order to save a patient's life, so you do this:

```
IO.puts "Set the defibrillator dials to these numbers: #{result}"
```

Here's what the user will see:

```
Set the defibrillator dials to these numbers: L@NO
```

Patient dies here.