# Elixir parsing string to integer

Tags: string, integer, elixir

I try to convert a list of strings into a list of integers. Here's the code:

```
list = ["114"]
list |> Enum.map(&String.to_integer(&1))
```

But the last line returns `'r'`. While `String.to_integer("114")` returns `114`
I tried `Integer.parse/1`, but it also gave me `'r'` (which its character code is 114):

```
list
|> Enum.map(&Integer.parse(&1))
|> Enum.map(fn {num, _} -> num end)
```

Why?

Comment: That's as expected. As noted by the single quotes, that's a charlist, which is equal to the list of integers you expect. You can perform operations on it however you need, it will just be displayed as a charlist, but it's just `[114]`

Comment: Check out this question and the answer as well as links in the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63473722/elixir-comprehension-returning-a-star-character/63476012#63476012

Comment: If you want to see the numbers in IEx instead of charlists you can configure how they're inspected: `IEx.configure(inspect: [charlists: :as_lists])`

Comment: Just adding this guide as a reference, I think it explains it quite well: https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/binaries-strings-and-char-lists.html#charlists

Answer (score 1):

As the other comments have pointed out, this confusing behavior is the result of Elixir "humanizing" charlists.  In a nutshell, Elixir (for historical reasons) can store un-encoded strings as lists of integers (called "charlists").  The take-away is that when all the members of a list are integers in the ASCII range (i.e. 0-127), then Elixir formats the display using the corresponding codepoints for each integer (`114` corresponds to `r`, for example).

See this answer for similar explanation: [Why does for x <- 3..4, do: x * 3 return '\t\f' in Elixir?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65135280/why-does-for-x-3-4-do-x-3-return-t-f-in-elixir/65136734#65136734)