# Why does for x <- 3..4, do: x * 3 return '\t\f' in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

In Elixir, why does the comprehension `for x <- 3..4, do: x * 2` result in `[6, 8]` but `for x <- 3..4, do: x * 3` results in `'\t\f'` ?

I'm executing this in the `iex` repl.

Comment: Take a look at [this answer and question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63473722/elixir-comprehension-returning-a-star-character/63476012#63476012)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of the most confusing gotchas in Elixir: the "humanizing" of charlists. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65087836/elixir-configure-a-mix-project-to-always-print-charlists-as-lists/65094901#65094901) for a question revolving around this same issue.

Charlists are lists of integer codepoints, used to represent un-encoded strings (more common in older Erlang libraries from the days before encodings were baked in).  So if you have a list of integers, Elixir (for historical reasons), has to guess whether or not you meant to represent a 'string' -- so if all the integers in that list are below 127, Elixir assumes that this must be a charlist that represents 'string' data and it prints out the corresponding ASCII characters to make a readable string.

You can reveal the actual inner representation by setting the `charlists: :as_lists` option in your calls to `IO.inspect/2`:

```
iex(1)> result = for x <- 3..4, do: x * 3
'\t\f'
iex(2)> IO.inspect(result, charlists: :as_lists)
[9, 12]
'\t\f'
```

or more simply:

```
iex> IO.inspect([9, 12], charlists: :as_lists)
[9, 12]
'\t\f'
```

This shows us the expected integers (9, 12), and if we bother to look these up in a Unicode or ASCII code chart, we would see that the `\t` and `\f` characters are represented by codepoints 9 and 12 respectively.

Keep in mind that these representations of the data are just visual -- the underlying data is 100% the same:

```
iex> [9, 12] === '\t\f'
true
```

Comment: Thank. you for the very clear answer.