# Different behavior between Enum.chunk(arr, 3) and Enum.chunk_every(arr, 3)

Tags: list, linked-list, elixir

i have a data structure of a flat array of numbers

```
[145, 46, 200, 3, 178, 206, 73, 228, 165, 65, 6, 141, 73, 90, 181, 100]
```

i need to make an array of arrays with a max of 3 items per sub array. So i look at some examples, and `Enum.chunk(arr, n)` seems like a candidate

so .chuck(arr, 3) says its deprecated, use chuck_every(arr, 3) instead, so i did that and it produces a strange result vs chunk

for example: chunk returns

```
[[145, 46, 200], [3, 178, 206], [73, 228, 165], [65, 6, 141], [73, 90, 181]]
```

while chunk_every returns

```
[145, 46, 200],
[3, 178, 206],
[73, 228, 165],
[65, 6, 141],
[73, 90, 181],
'p']
```

the main difference being an extra random element which is a string???

it's almost like it converted the element that chunk cuts off and converts it to a string?

Naturally I am expecting the replacement method would have the same output given the same input. Right?

Comment: _Sidenote:_ `'d'` is not “a string” by any mean, it’s _a charlist_ effectively equal to `[100]`: `[100] == 'd' #⇒ true`.

Comment: _Sidenote:_ [tag:elixir] does not have arrays (unless you use `:array` module from [tag:erlang].) There are lists only.

Comment: It's a good job you asked about `chunk` vs `chunk_every`, otherwise this would have been closed as a duplicate of [Elixir lists interpreted as char lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30037914/elixir-lists-interpreted-as-char-lists).

Answer (score 4):

Look at last element: 100. `chunk` seems to discard that value while `chunk_every` add it at last element alone. That is the `p` character you see. Elixir try to show as chars  arrays of numbers in the console, as that is its internal representation.

As you can see in the documentation, you can pass `:discard` as leftover parameter to behave as deprecated `chunk` function.

https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#chunk_every/2

Comment: so based on the docs i adjusted to 

`Enum.chunk_every(arr, 3, 3, :discard)`. to get the same result as just `chunk(arr, 3)`

seems a bit odd but i guess this is saying chunk the array into 3 elements every 3 elements and discard the remainder?

Comment: That's it. It's kind a generic more powerful function

Comment: i have to admit, at first i was a bit resistant to the new signature, but you're right it nice to have a more generic function for chunking

Comment: Please, add examples on the main reply, as @DenisSDujota did on the comment.

Answer (score 1):

`Enum.chunk_every/4` was designed by this,
actually its a number if you do like this:

```
[145, 46, 200, 3, 178, 206, 73, 228, 165, 65, 6, 141, 73, 90, 181, 100]
|> Enum.chunk_every(3, 3, [])
|> Enum.each(fn item ->
  IO.inspect item, charlists: false
end)
```

you can find more detail from official discussion:

https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/issues/7260

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question regarding the difference between `chunk`, and `chunk_every`. It just points out the charlists behaviour, which is already answered on [Elixir lists interpreted as char lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30037914/elixir-lists-interpreted-as-char-lists).

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it makes sense to implement basic functionality ourselves, instead of looking up the standard library, for the precisely controlled result.

Here is a recursive implementation, that discards the tail.

```elixir
input =
  [145, 46, 200, 3, 178, 206, 73, 228,
   165, 65, 6, 141, 73, 90, 181, 100]

defmodule MyEnum do
  def chunk_3(input), do: do_chunk_3(input, [])
  defp do_chunk_3([e1, e2, e3 | rest], acc),
    do: do_chunk_3(rest, [[e1, e2, e3] | acc])
  defp do_chunk_3(_, acc), do: Enum.reverse(acc)
end

MyEnum.chunk_3(input)
#⇒ [[145, 46, 200],
#   [3, 178, 206],
#   [73, 228, 165],
#   [65, 6, 141],
#   [73, 90, 181]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone finds themselves here because they are doing the Udemy course on Elixir and Phoenix, the number "100" listed as the last element in the list on the original question is incorrect.

These numbers come from an example in that course that is using an Erlang hashing algorithm for the letters "asdf".

`:crypto.hash(:md5, "asdf")`

In Elixir that will return:

```
[145, 46, 200, 3, 178, 206, 73, 228, 165, 65, 6, 141, 73, 90, 181, 112]
```

The number 112 is actually the ASCII code for a lower-case English alphabet `p`

As suggested above, the function in the Udemy course would need to be updated as so:

```
def build_grid(%Identicon.Image{hex: hex} = image) do
   hex
   |> Enum.chunk_every(3, 3, :discard)
   |> Enum.map(&mirror_row/1)
end
```